# Sign up using G+ (Google+) using kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am working on some android application and want to add **Sign up** functionality for users.

Users are expected to sign up using **google+** or **Facebook**.
Any idea how to do this using python and kivy?

[This link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) is great, but need a little help from python developers.

Answer (score 3):

The link in your question shows how to call the Google Play Services API to sign in. To call the API from Python, you need to use a library called [Pyjnius](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#pyjnius) which is mentioned on the Kivy docs to wrap the Android classes in a Python class.

You should be able to do something similar with the Facebook API after installing the [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android). Some users have found problems integrating these SDKs into their Kivy projects, with some discussion and solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721294/kivy-and-google-play-services).